# Rerunning a script of scripts

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

At work, I use a lot of pre-written scripts when doing production deployments, so I started creating master scripts containing these scripts that I use, mostly to save typing. I add 'pause' commands between each script so if there's an error, I can break out of the master script and fix the problem.  At that point, I have to edit the master script and delete what has already run so it doesn't get re-run before I can start up the master script again.  I know there is no goto command in sqlplus, but is there any way of writing a SQL script that can essentially pick up where it left off?

Just for clarity, the master script looks like this:

```
@script1.sql
```

pause Script 1 completed.  Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue

```
@script2.sql
```

pause Script 2 completed.  Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>  to continue

```
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: That's where a shell script might be useful.

Comment: If this is for your schema migration you might want to have a look at tools like Liquibase or Flyway which can do all that for you

Answer (score 0):

If you can create tables/procedures, this can be an approach.
Say we have 3 scripts to run:

**script1.sql:**

```
create table table_script_1(id number);
```

**script2.sql**

```
create ta_ERROR_HERE_!!!!!!_ble table_script_2(id number);
```

**script3.sql**

```
create table table_script_3(id number);
```

We can create a table in which we store the scripts to run, in order of execution, and a procedure to handle this table:

```
create table script_to_run (num number, script varchar2(256), status varchar2(10));

create or replace procedure update_script (p_script varchar2, p_status varchar2) is
pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
    update script_to_run
    set status = p_status
    where script = p_script;
    commit;
end;
/
```

In this way, we use the table to say what script we have to run, and in which order:

```
insert into script_to_run values (1, 'd:\script1.sql', 'TO_RUN');
insert into script_to_run values (2, 'd:\script2.sql', 'TO_RUN');
insert into script_to_run values (3, 'd:\script3.sql', 'TO_RUN');
commit;
```

At this point, our main script will simply read the table, run the first script still not executed and then call himself recursively, to run the next script:

**main_script.sql:**

```
column script new_val script
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT
select script
from script_to_run
where num = (   select min(num)
                from script_to_run
                where nvl(status, 'KO') != 'OK' );
start &script
exec update_script('&script', 'OK');
prompt 'Script &script OK'
start d:\main_script.sql
```

Now we run the main script ( while script2.sql contains errors) and check the result:

```
SQL> select 1 from table_script_1;

no rows selected

SQL> select 1 from table_script_2;
select 1 from table_script_2
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select 1 from table_script_3;
select 1 from table_script_3
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
SQL> select * from script_to_run;

       NUM SCRIPT                                             STATUS
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------
         1 d:\script1.sql                                     OK
         2 d:\script2.sql                                     TO_RUN
         3 d:\script3.sql                                     TO_RUN
```

Only script1 ran OK, script2 had error3, and script3 never ran.

After fixing the script2.sql, we run again the main script, without modifying  it; in the second run, the main script only executes script2 and script3, not script1.
The final result:

```
SQL> select 1 from table_script_2;

no rows selected

SQL> select 1 from table_script_3;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from script_to_run;

       NUM SCRIPT                                             STATUS
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------
         1 d:\script1.sql                                     OK
         2 d:\script2.sql                                     OK
         3 d:\script3.sql                                     OK

SQL>
```